# Why doesnt this method redirect my output from .exe [ffmpeg]?

Tags: c#, redirect, ffmpeg, console-application

I have the method:

```
public static string StartProcess(string exePathArg, string argumentsArg, int timeToWaitForProcessToExit)
    {
        string retMessage = "";

        using (Process p = new Process())
        {
            p.StartInfo.FileName = exePathArg;
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            p.StartInfo.Arguments = argumentsArg;
            p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;



            try
            {
                p.Start();
                StreamReader myOutput = p.StandardOutput;

                retMessage = "STANDARD OUTPUT: " +  myOutput.ReadToEnd();

                p.WaitForExit(timeToWaitForProcessToExit);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            { 
                retMessage = "EXCEPTION THROWN: " + ex.ToString();

            }
            finally
            {
                try
                {
                    p.Kill();
                }
                catch { }
            }
        }

        return retMessage;
    }
```

But it doesnt redirect my output to retMessage. Anyone any ideas? I tested the arguments in a bat file and output is definitely output.

Cheers,
Pete

Comment: Maybe the process doesn't write to StandardOutput but only to StandardError?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My guess (agree with dtb's comment):
AFAIK `ffmpeg` uses stdout to pipe out binary data(multimedia, snapshots, etc.) and stderr is used for logging purposes. In your example you use stdout.

So, change you code to:

```
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    ...
    string log = p.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
```

and it should solve your problem.

Comment: GREAT! thats sorted it thanks for the post really helped I never would have thoughto to check, thanks again!

Comment: I had same problem with ffmpeg's output. StandardOutput returns empty, all the output comes from standardError.. I hope this would save someone else's time.