# Processing video using ffmpeg and saving the output to MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, ffmpeg, video-processing

I have user uploaded video saved in a folder (can be in any of 5/6 formats)
I have 2 needs.

- Extract 3 frame images (that I will show to user for possible thumbnail
- Convert the video to one or more other formats (flv + WebM)

I am planning to use FFMPEG command line tool.

How do I write the output from FFMPEG to MongoDB gridFS?

Is it even possible or I have to write the files to folder first & then save to gridFS?

Thanks

Comment: Which programming language are you using?

Comment: Does FFMPEG support redirecting output to something other than a file (like /dev/stdout)?

Comment: Also, not sure where you'll host this as any hosted MongoDb solution is likely to be far more expensive than just using something like Amazon or Azure's blob hosting. (As video files will be large).

Comment: I am using C# in MVC 3

Comment: @WiredPrairie: Not sure if Amazon/Azure's blob hosting will cost less. I need auto sharding, chunking and a distributed system.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why doesnt this method redirect my output from .exe \[ffmpeg\]?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4246758/why-doesnt-this-method-redirect-my-output-from-exe-ffmpeg)